# A program with for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, post-increment, pre-increment

I was writing a `for` loop program when this code came across my mind.

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++,i++)
```

The program works fine and the output is also correct. But then I tried the following code:

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; ++i,++i)

for(int i=1; i<=10; ++i,i++)

for(int i=1; i<=10; i++,++i)
```

To my amazement, all of them produce the same output, 1 3 5 7 9. Now my question is, how exactly do `for` loops work and why did all the code produce the same output when I used pre-increment and post-increment in the same `for` loop?

Comment: Hint: if you're not using the *value* of the pre/post-increment expression, what do you think the difference is?

Comment: i++, ++i would "eventually" increase i by one. in this case the overall results of i matters thus it wouldn't make difference

Comment: Take a look at - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14 - it should help :)

Comment: Actually you should write i += 2 instead of i++, i++ or another variant.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I forgot to mention that I printed the value of i in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using multiple elements seperated by a comma is only (potentially) problematic if the order of their execution matters.

If you're not using the result of a post/preincrement, and the only thing that matters is the increment itself, then clearly the net result will be the same - adding 2.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Understood the answer.

Answer (score 5):

it's equivalent to

```
int i = 1;
while(i <= 10)
{
   //stuff would happen here but these loops are all empty
   i++;
   i++;
}
```

and

```
int i = 1;
while(i <= 10)
{
   //stuff would happen here but these loops are all empty
   ++i;
   ++i;
}
```

and

```
int i = 1;
while(i <= 10)
{
   //stuff would happen here but these loops are all empty
   ++i;
   i++;
}
```

and

```
int i = 1;
while(i <= 10)
{
   //stuff would happen here but these loops are all empty
   i++;
   ++i;
}
```

In which case whether it's pre-increment or post-increment, it doesn't matter at all. It just increments the value of `i` by `1`.

Comment: In i++, the value is first used before increasing and in ++i, the value is first increased before using. In that case, Shouldn't the code with ++i and i++ lead to different results ?

Comment: You execute the statement and you're not using the result for anything else. This difference would come out only if you used it in cases like `list.remove(i--);` or `array[++i] = element;`.

Comment: But just calling `i++;` or `++i;` doesn't really do much other than the intended effect which is pretty much equal to `i += 1;` or so `i = i + 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

`i++` means use then increment with a copy and  incremented happen later in that line

`++i` means increment and use without a copy and increment happen immediately.

That's is the deference here.

Comment: @ Ruchira Gayan - I know the difference between i++ and ++i. But my question is that why do they produce the same output although their functioning is slightly different ?

Comment: @Codin'Genius Then you have the answer.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I understood the working method.